# How can i use Cloud Firestore and Firebase Auth for windows

Tags: firebase, flutter

i have a app both mobile and web in flutter so i want to create for desktop App, but base on the plugin does not support windows..
How can i use cloud Firestore and Firebase Auth in windows

Answer (score 0):

Since the plugins don't support it, and there are no SDKs for Windows for either of the products, the most likely only option is to wrap the REST API that both provide. See: [Auth REST API](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/rest/auth) and the [Firestore REST API](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/reference/rest).

It might also be worth checking out the [Firestore gRPC API](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/reference/rpc) and its [.NET client library](https://cloud.google.com/dotnet/docs/reference/Google.Cloud.Firestore/latest), although I'm not sure if the latter is meant for use in client-side code or just for use in a trusted environment.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem with desktop app in c#, there is not a lot of examples on the web. You are asking about flutter but I think my answer still should help you as the implementation is less important than concept.

You need to call your service and ask for custom_token, next with this custom_token you are calling google service and exchange custom_token for access_token. With this access_token you can call your service.

I created the the solution react.js+python+c#+firebase to have example for a future.

[image]

You can check the example on [github](https://github.com/ProductivityTools-Learning/ProductivityTools.Example.FirebaseAuthentication)

[image: Working web application]

The firebase documentation regarding this topic is [here](https://firebase.google.com/docs/auth/admin/create-custom-tokens?hl=en#python_2)